# Discord.py How to turn off the microphone status of the discord bot (but not mute the bot)?

Tags: python, discord.py

My question is that: after writing the join function for the bot (code below), the bot **can join the voice channel successfully but it will show its microphone is on**. (I didn't let him play anything, it's just a join voice channel function).
My join function:

```
@Test011.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(Test011.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected(): # User in voice channel & Bot also in voice channel somewhere else maybe.
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:  # bot is not in the channel, let it connect.
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot is connected to {channel}.")

    await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel}.")
```

The microphone on screenshot (I didn't let it play anything): 
[image]

The bot "Test001" is microphone on since it has a green "ring" around its avatar.

I do **not** want to mute the bot because I tried `Guilds.change_voice_state`.

**I want to let the bot join but not with microphone on if I don't process further commands.**

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: The bot has the green ring around when it's "speaking", if you stop the sound it will dissapear

Comment: yes I know it's speaking but it shouldn't since I didn't let him play any sound.